# Interfacing a modelica model and a Java one

Tags: java, modelica

I have a model developed with Dymola and I have to interface it with a model in Java.
More precisely, at each time step, both models provides the other with inputs.

So far, i've found that:
- Dymola is able to produce/export C code. They provide an incomprehensible (so far) interface but the main point is that the export is for Visual C++ only and i need to be cross-platform. 
- OpenModelica (OMC) can produce C code but i didn't find if it is useable as a library.

If you have any advice on how to interface a modelica and a Java model, please share it ;)

Answer (score 1):

There are several approaches to your problem. To give a few alternatives off the top of my head:

- Co-simulation. Dymola/OpenModelica can export models as FMU, so if you can export your Java code as FMU or write a master algorithm in Java, you can simulate them together. As far as I know that is the only way to use the simulation code generated by either tool as a library. I could be wrong about Dymola though.
- Time-events. when sample(...) ... communicate(). This has the advantage that both models can use different time-steps and variable step size solvers.

  - Using external C + JNI (Java Native Interface) to call some Java function at each event
  - Synchronization+Communication based on sockets

Answer (score 0):

It isn't clear from your description whether this Java code has some mathematical aspect to it or do you just want to use it as functions to compute values (or call it at specific intervals during the simulation).  If you could elaborate, it could help in figuring out what really makes sense here.