# Is there any method that support calling Modelica operator from Java

Tags: modelica

Is there any method that support calling `Modelica` operator from `java` ?
If I want to use the `Modelica` Operator like `der()`, `pre()` and so on, call them from `java`.

Is there any technology I can use?

Comment: `der` and `pre` are features of the Modelica language, "calling them from Java" makes no sense. Please explain in more detail what you want to achieve. Do you want to simulate a Modelica model using Java? Do you want to use Java functions in a Modelica model?

Comment: Thanks for your help. I want to simulate a Modelica model using java.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways to simulate Modelica models from a Java program. To directly simulate the Modelica code, use the Java interface of an existing Modelica simulator:

- OpenModelica's [Java interface](http://www.ep.liu.se/ecp/043/020/ecp09430121.pdf)
- [Java interface](https://www.modelica.org/events/modelica2006/Proceedings/sessions/Session5a3.pdf) for Dymola

Another option is to export the Modelica code to a *Functional Mockup Unit* (FMU) via the *Functional Mockup Interface* (FMI), e.g. using Dymola. Then use a Java FMI library (e.g. [JFMI](http://ptolemy.eecs.berkeley.edu/java/jfmi/)) to interact with the FMU. Note that you'll probably need to supply the solver code yourself. However this is far easier for an FMU than for raw Modelica code.

Also see [this question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11156299/interfacing-a-modelica-model-and-a-java-one) for more information about exchaning information between Modelica and Java.